# A scalar field of smooth transitions between two functions. What properties will it have?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

Let us say that I have two real valued 1 dimensional functions, $f,g$ of variable $x\in \mathbb R$.

Now if I introduce a new variable $y$ let them be boundary conditions along $$\begin{cases}f: &y=0\\g: &y=k\end{cases}$$ of a energy minimization functional for a scalar field $\phi$:

$$\min_\phi\left\{\int_{\mathcal B}\|\nabla^k\phi\|_2^2\right\}\\ \mathcal B \text{ being the "box" (or suitable limit) :} \cases{-\infty \leq x\leq \infty\\0\leq y \leq k}$$

And $k$ being typically $1$ (gradient) or $2$ (laplacian or maybe hessian).

(If still unclear, $\phi$ must assume $f$ on $y=0$ and $g$ on $y=k$)

Can we derive any particular properties for $\phi$ given this setup?

---

**EDIT**: I have done some experiments with my computational framework (for $k=2$), like the one below with $$\cases{f(x) = \sin(3x)\\g(x) = \sin(12x)}$$

[image]

Color coded resulting image. Note how 3/4 of the high frequency flames slowly get "extinguished" as we rise towards $f$. Maybe an easier to understand depiction would be a video where the time increases linearly with *decreasing* $y$ coordinate (from up and downward on the above color image):
[image: ![enter image description here]